# How UIPickerView get XML datasource and onchange to another UIPickerView?

Tags: ios4

1) Can there two UIPickerView on the same View?

I mean can there are 2 drop down menu on the same view?

2) How can UIPickerView's option value be retrieved from a XML file?

3) When I select an item in the first UIPickerView, it passed the selected value to the second UIPickerView in order to display corresponding list of option which also get from XML file. Can it be done?

Does any tutorial discuss it? And, what are the proper ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can have as many pickers as we need using add subview and remove subviews options

First of all parse the xml file using nsxmlparser and store the first picker values ina an array,now create a picker programatically and add those array values to that first picker

In parser did selected object at index methode,,parse the secound xml file and store in another array

now add the secound picker to the view using  add subview

Note :Dont forgot to add uipickerdelegate in .h